# How to set the application icon for push notifications using ionic?

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap-pushplugin

I'm trying to set the default icon application changing the following .java file inside the PushPlugin directory.

`plugins/com.phonegap.plugins.PushPlugin/src/android/com/plugin/gcm/GCMIntentService.java`

But the changes won't stay. Ionic generates this file automatically. I'm aware that you can [change the badge](https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin) on the icon of the application but I need to change the icon itself.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper way to do this is to fork the plugin, make your modifications in your fork and then reinstall the plugin from your fork.